# Why does the 3DS Max symmetry modifier affect the length of my object?

Tags: 3ds-max

I am having an issue with the 3DS Max symmetry modifier, where it is truncating part of my geometry.

I am trying to use the it to mirror a corner, but when the modifier is turned on, the length of the section it is mirroring is reduced.

The length of the mirrored segment is shortened the more rotated the mirror is, up to a 45 degree angle. How can I avoid this happening?

[image]

Comment: Hello. While there is a tag and while you think this is the right place to ask. Be aware that this is probably not a conductive place to ask this question. You may get an aswwe but it will take much longer than your willing to wait.